# How to avoid method length creep when using LINQ and vars

Tags: c#, .net, linq, methods, var

I'm using vars to capture anonymous types which are selected into from tables in the DB. It's great, I love it. However, since vars cannot be method parameters, this technique promotes the evolution of overly-long methods that cannot be decomposed e.g.

```
...
var res1 = (from t1 in dao.t1
            select new { t1.Id, t1.Cost, t1.Size }).ToList();

<do stuff with res1 ...> 

var res2 = (from r1 in res1 where r1.Cost > 100 
         select new { r1.Id, r1.Size }).ToList();

<do stuff with res2 ...> 

var res3 = (from r2 in res2 where r2.Size > 5
             select new { r2.Id }.ToList();

<do stuff with res3 ...>
```

Now AFAIK I can't decompose these selects into methods due to the vars. But naturally I don't want to create named types for these intermediary variables as that'd be really clunky and bloaty. So I'm stuck with excessively long methods, Right?

Comment: Not all of those need anonymous types at all.

Comment: well let's say that t1 really has 25 columns and you are selecting out 15. And then you're grouping those into 10 and so on.

Comment: There's no reason at all of that third query to be of an anonymous type; it should be a `List<int>` or whatever the type of `Id` is.  There's no reason for an anonymous type with only one value.

Comment: @Servy see my comment about the actual number of columns (i.e. many more than one).

Comment: @sming Sure, which is why the above comment wasn't an answer to the question, merely a comment that in that particular case, you shouldn't have used an anonymous type.  If you're not in that case, then it may well be appropriate.  The answer I posted answers the actual question.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an anonymous type and you find yourself wishing to use it beyond the scope of a single method, then it's time to promote that anonymous type up to a new named type; use that instead of the anonymous class for the information, and then you can freely extract portions of the method out into other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unless you create your own classes to handle results, or return something different then anonymous types (e.g. `Tuple<...>`s).

> [**Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)
>
> If you must store query results or pass them outside the method boundary, consider using an ordinary named struct or class instead of an anonymous type.

There is also another possibility to get anonymous type out from method with intellisense: use generics and generic type inference. But I don't think it applies to your case.